# ImageGallery and ImageGrid in android

Tags: android

I have created an image gallery in android , now whenever i will click on image on a gallery then that particular image will get added into Grid View.

my layout has image gallery on top and image grid in bottom (so i have used LinerLayout Vertical )

so can anyone tell me how to achieve this in android ?

Comment: The onClick of the gallery should add to the adapter of the GridView

Comment: i wanna to add images into grid view as an when i click on image gallery

Answer (score 0):

```
    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);    
    g.setAdapter(new Gallerydapter(this));


    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(PhotoGallery.this);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(45, 45));
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);

    mGrid.addView(imageView);
   }
```

I have used the above code to add images in grid view , is this the efficient code ? i mean is this code gonna generate running out of memory error